# submitting a form in ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using ionic 4.12.  I have the following code for the form:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <form  #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form)">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Guest Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input  name="guestname" type="text" placeholder="Guest Name" ngModel></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Host Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input  name="host_name" type="text" placeholder="Host Name" ngModel></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <button type="submit" block ion-button>Register Guest</button>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

and here is the ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-register-guest',
  templateUrl: 'register-guest.html',
})
export class RegisterGuestPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  }
  public submitForm(form){
    console.log("form submitted YAY");
  }
}
```

When pressing the submit button, nothing is logged in the console.  I think the maybe methods from the ts file are not accesible in the view.  When I try `<button (click)="test">test</button>` and setup a method called test to just `console.log`, nothing happens.  How should I fix this?

Comment: Ionic 4 uses '@ionic/angular'

But I'm not sure why you use @IonicPage(). Maybe to make it work, you can try to delete it. Then make sure you have imported the page inside the routing page.

Comment: I have check about it, IonicPage decorator doesn't exist in v4 https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14956

Comment: your code here is Ionic v3 code, you should check examples for how things are in v4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things I would try:
In your @Component I would change to this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-register-guest',
  templateUrl: './register-guest.html',
})
```

Also delete `@IonicPage()` and `import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';`

Furthermore change your button to:

```
<ion-button type="submit" expand="block">Register Guest</ion-button>
```